# Many leaks showing in Instruments caused by Array and Dictionary

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, swift3, instruments

I was testing my app using Instruments checking for any leaks and to my surprise it's showing many leaks caused mainly by:

```
_ContiguousArrayStorage<String>
_ContiguousArrayStorage<Int>
_ContiguousArrayStorage<NSLayoutConstraint>

_NativeDictionaryStorageOwner<Int, CGFloat>
_NativeDictionaryStorageOwner<String, AnyObject>
```

The tests are done on an iPhone 5s, iPhone 6s and iPad Pro. All of the devices are running iOS 10.

---

[image: Cycle & Roots]

[image: Leaks]

What can I do about these leaks?

Comment: Do you have circular references in your collections? E.g. `let a = [Any](); let b = [Any](); a.append(b); b.append(a)`

Comment: No, I don't have that. Many of these leaks happens at initialization / viewDidLoad. They are just sitting there as properties.

Comment: It seems it only happens on devices running iOS 10.

Comment: See my answer to this similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449316/leaks-in-swift-3-ios-10/41621918#41621918