# Memory leak _ContiguousArrayStorage?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, memory-leaks

I'm new to swift.I'm running instrument tool for memory leaks.I found a leak `"_ContiguousArrayStorage<String>"`

[image: Screen Shot of Instruments]

Its leading to below part of the code

```
let myData = NSData(data: request.value!)
let buffer = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>(myData.bytes), count: myData.length))
```

[image: Screenshot of code leakage lines]

Can anyone help me out?.

Anything wrong with above code?

Edit:
Adding some more code.

```
let myData = NSData(data: request.value!)
var buffer = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>(myData.bytes), count: myData.length))

let responseArray: [CUnsignedChar] = Array(buffer)

let responseValue = BluetoothCommunicationManager.sharedInstance.parseData(responseArray,length: myData.length).0

let responseName = BluetoothCommunicationManager.sharedInstance.parseData(responseArray,length: myData.length).1

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(responseName, object: request, userInfo: responseValue as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

The parseData method of the singleton class returns NSMutableDictionary.

```
func parseData(responseData: [CUnsignedChar]) -> NSMutableDictionary
{
        let infoDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        let subIndexValue = Int(responseData[5])
        infoDictionary.setValue(subIndexValue, forKey: KEY_SUB_INDEX)
        return responseData
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've listed, that would cause a leak. The Instruments readout (I'm assuming you're running a generation of <5 minutes) indicates that you;re initiating Array objects and not releasing them. The likely candidate is either a for loop, or an un-released parent (often a VC). Can you go over your app, and look for instances of [String]? Also, if  Instruments is pointing you to that bit of code, put a print statement at the start of writingData:, to make sure it's not being called over and over.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments.Let me add some more code...

Comment: @dylanthelion.. I have added some more code..waiting for ur feedback

Comment: Cool. It's late here, and I'm gonna walk home, but I'll check this out if you leave another comment, when I'm home. Good luck!

Comment: I've had similar problems and according to bdmontz in my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449316/leaks-in-swift-3-ios-10 it's because "if you create a Swift object from Objective-C code and the Swift object has a native Swift dictionary property, you will see this leak. This also applies to Swift Set's and NSSet's. I also saw that the leak happens on iOS 10 and not on iOS 9." And I guess it's the same with `Array` and `NSArray`.

Comment: @HennyLee..I'm not creating any swift object using Objective-C code....Please look at parseData function in my question, where I'm creating NSMutableDictionary

Comment: Yea I was just pasting bdmontz's answer. To be honest, I'm not totally sure what he meant. My guess is, in the case of `Array`, it has something to do with what happens under the hood (converting to `NSArray` and vice versa) and most probably when using Obj-C objects. Btw if you run it on iOS 9, you won't see these leaks.

Comment: Now I don't know much about the technical stuff of Swift and Obj-C, but I think `UnsafeBufferPointer(start: UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>(myData.bytes), count: myData.length)` is just a "Swifty" way of the original in Obj-C which should be still an Obj-C object.

Comment: The added code seems like it only adds two lines to what was already in your screenshot? So, I can add that the line "var buffer = "..., is something that generates a contiguous array, but the problem is still, the there's nothing in the code you've listed, that indicates why the writingData: func would ever be called more than once. Where is this method called?

Comment: Yes @dylanthelion it will be called multiple times..It's a delegate method, whenever BLE device writes to my device the method will get called...It receives request.value(NSData) which i am converting to bytes array and then passing to a singleton class called BLECommManager,where I have written a parser method listed above(parseData), which returns NSMutableDictionary...

Comment: @HennyLee...Thanks alot...let me check once and get back to you...

Comment: @MasterStroke , Even i am facing the leak issues in swift3. So, can you cross-check the line at which the leak is generating..
Go to leaks -> (Details)call tree option.
Then hide system libraries -> separate by thread -> invert call tree.
paste here the function at which the leak is happening.

Comment: MasterStroke,@iSwift, so does anyone has a [small reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Or should we just guess by screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to convert the `NSData` to an array of `CUnsignedChar`. You don't need to use `UnsafeBufferPointer` or `UnsafePointer` to do that conversion. I suspect your use of the unsafe pointers is the root cause of your memory leak.

You can just create the array by passing it a `Data` object instead of an `NSData` object. Try this instead:

```
let myData = NSData(data: request.value!) as Data
let responseArray = [CUnsignedChar](myData)

let responseValue = BluetoothCommunicationManager.sharedInstance.parseData(responseArray, length: responseArray.count).0

let responseName = BluetoothCommunicationManager.sharedInstance.parseData(responseArray, length: responseArray.count).1
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @pwc..But seems like Data is not available in swift 2.3..I'm getting "Use of undeclared type 'Data'" compilation error.

Comment: I should have realized using NSData signaled you weren't on Swift 3 yet. Out of curiosity, is there any particular reason why you haven't migrated?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a project that was NOT a mixture of Objective-C and Swift. It turned out that string interpolation can leak memory:

http://www.openradar.me/26761490

The TL;DR is to update your string interpolations to string concatenations instead.

So:

```
print("Cannot write to characteristic \(request.characteristic.UUID)")
```

Becomes:

```
print("Cannot write to characteristic " + request.characteristic.UUID)
```