# Use [weak] to prevent Memory Leak in model not working by swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, reference

I have a question about memory leak.
I want to release memory, using [weak self] but it seems fail to release.
How to release memory successful?

[image: Memory graph like this.]

Code:

```
class City:NSObject {
    let notifySubject = PublishSubject<Any>()

    var id:String = ""
    @objc var name:String = ""
    var kind:String = ""
    var userId:String = ""
    var country:String = ""
    var subject:String = ""
    var descriptions:String = ""
    var cities:[City] = [City]()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(_ id:String) {
        super.init()
        self.id = id
    }

    func getData() {

        API.Data.get({ json in

            json.forEach({ [weak self] (index, data) in
                self?.cities.append(City(data))
            })
            self.fromJson(json)
            self.notifySubject.onNext(json)
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: `foreach` isn’t what likely needs weak reference. The `API.Data.get` is more likely candidate. And even then, we can’t tell because you haven’t shared details of the alleged strong reference cycle. Don’t just start throwing weak references around, but look at the graph (not just the list of leaked objects) to figure out where the cycle exists.

Comment: Share not just the list of leaked objects, but the actual ownership graph for one of them. And if not immediately obvious, use “malloc stack” feature to figure out where those strong references where established. But we can’t diagnose this on the basis of what’s been provided thus far.

Comment: Are you using iOS 10.2? there is a leak bug related to use of swift arrays in  classes that inherit from NSObject as you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602301/swift-3-enums-leak-memory-when-the-class-contains-an-array here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449316/leaks-in-swift-3-ios-10 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392362/many-leaks-showing-in-instruments-caused-by-array-and-dictionary

Comment: Thanks advice. I try to do it.